# How do I remove a curled package?

Tags: command-line, uninstall, curl

I ran the following command:

```
curl -o- https://deb.packages.mattermost.com/repo-setup.sh
```

and it doesn't work.
How can I remove this curled package and try the installation again?

Comment: That's not a "package." That's merely a file of some sort, possibly a shell script. You are aware that downloaded files are not executable? You must take additional steps to make the file executable, and then to actually run the script to do whatever it does.

Comment: Pls be more elaborate about what did not work. Perhaps add the output of the terminal to your question.

Comment: @d1bro Sure, will do so tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

`curl` only downloads the file given to it as @user535733 pointed out in the comments. Not knowing what exactly you try to the proper way might be:

```
curl -O https://deb.packages.mattermost.com/repo-setup.sh
chmod +x repo-setup.sh
sudo repo-setup.sh
```

You could even do as described in [the Mattermost documentation](https://docs.mattermost.com/install/mattermost-omnibus.html):

```
curl -o- https://deb.packages.mattermost.com/repo-setup.sh | sudo bash
```

Comment: The last command you typed is exactly the one I had tried yesterday night, and it had workec (just that it complained about `bash`, if I remember correctly). I had also followed the link yesterday, and then typed `sudo apt-get install mattermost-omnibus`, and I get the error: `E: Unable to locate package mattermost-omnibus`. But I'm not on a server or so, it's plain-old 18.04 LTS.

Comment: @Anonymous5638 hi, I sadly do not know why the last given command failed on you, but the three mentioned before  should do the trick. I hope the helped you in achieving your goal.  Plus, a friendly note for future questions you might ask here: be as elaborate about what you tried, also where you got your info from and what exactly the output or error message is - this makes it easier for others to help you e.g . you only provided a part of the command you tried, leaving out that part that failed you. just so you understand: `|`passes the output of the first command to the second. peace